# Getting 401 error even after adding successful authentication to SecurityContextHolder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, amazon-cognito

I'm using aws cognito token validations to my springboot api. It getting authenticated successfully and assigning security context. But still it throwing 401 unauthorized error.

Sample code:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
     Authentication authentication;
     try {
        authentication = this.cognitoIdTokenProcessor.authenticate ((HttpServletRequest)request);
         if (authentication != null) {
             SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
         }
      } catch (Exception var6) {
            logger.error("Cognito ID Token processing error", var6);
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

here authentication is success but getting 401 error. can some please help me.

Comment: where are your debug logs, voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In my pom.xml file there is two types securities one is token and second one is oauth. I commented the oauth dependencies and then is working now.